# Changing default location of "Program Files (x86)" doesn't work

Tags: windows-8, 64-bit, windows-registry, 32-bit, 32-vs-64-bit

I changed the default location of "Program Files" and "Program Files (x86)" by editing the Registry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion]
"ProgramFilesDir"="E:\\ProgramFiles\\64bits"
"CommonFilesDir"="E:\\CommonFiles\\64bits"
"ProgramFilesDir (x86)"="E:\\ProgramFiles\\32bits"
"CommonFilesDir (x86)"="E:\\CommonFiles\\32bits"
"CommonW6432Dir"="E:\\CommonFiles\\64bits"
"ProgramW6432Dir"="E:\\ProgramFiles\\64bits"
```

For 64-bit apps, it is working fine.

But for 32-bit apps, this configuration is not working! All apps try to install in "C:\Program Files (x86)", and I need to change this location manually. After installing in "E:\ProgramFiles\32bits" (which exists), the app works fine. These apps are: NVIDIA Driver, VMware Workstation 12, VLC, Steam, Free Download Manager, Partition Wizard.

Why is this Registry change not working? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not working"? Do you mean that the programs you've installed are not working, or that when you install a program it is still prompting to install to the original location, or something else?

Comment: sorry, I clarified the question. "...All apps try to install in "c:\Program Files (x86)", and I need to change this location manually..."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When 32-bit programs access [certain parts of the Registry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384253), they are subject to [WOW64 redirection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384232(v=vs.85).aspx). For compatibility purposes, they get a different view of the Registry than what's actually there. Therefore, installer programs that are 32-bit don't see your changes.

You need to also change the values in this path:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion
```

Then 32-bit applications will see and use the settings you choose.